# GXT GridFilters issue

Tags: java, filter, gxt

I had revamp my question. I am trying `GridFilters` on my webapp. But it does not work for "More than one filters".
When i only add one filter, it works.

For example only works

```
filters.addFilters(classFilter);
```

Or

```
filters.addFilters(studentNameFilter);
```

But didn't works with

```
filters.addFilters(classFilter);
filters.addFilters(studentNameFilter);
```

I tried to follow `https://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#filtergrid` but it seems like doesn't works for me. How should i solve this problem?

Here is my coding:

```
ColumnModel cm = getColumnModel();
ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
cp.setBodyBorder(true);  
cp.setHeadingHtml("Filter Grid");
cp.setLayout(new FitLayout());  
cp.setSize(660, 300);

GridFilters filters = new GridFilters();  
filters.setLocal(true);

StringFilter studentNameFilter = new StringFilter(StudentModelData.STUDENT_NAME);
StringFilter classFilter = new StringFilter(StudentModelData.CLASS);

filters.addFilter(studentNameFilter);
filters.addFilter(classFilter);

ListStore<StudentModelData> store = new ListStore<StudentModelData>();  
List<StudentModelData> tempStudentModelData = new ArrayList<StudentModelData>();
List<ModelData> modelData = event.<List<ModelData>> getData();
for (int i = 0; i < modelData.size(); i++) {
    tempStudentModelData.add((StudentModelData) modelData.get(i));
    store.add(tempStudentModelData.get(i));
}
final Grid<StudentModelData> grid = new Grid<StudentModelData>(store, cm);
grid.getView().setForceFit(true);  
grid.setStyleAttribute("borderTop", "none");  
grid.setAutoExpandColumn("name");  
grid.setBorders(false);  
grid.setStripeRows(true);  
grid.setColumnLines(true);  
grid.addPlugin(filters);  
cp.add(grid);
container.add(cp);
```

ColumnModel

```
public ColumnModel getColumnModel() {
List<ColumnConfig> configs = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
configs.add(new ColumnConfig(StudentModelData.STUDENT_NAME, "Student Name", 130));
configs.add(new ColumnConfig(StudentModelData.CLASS, "Class", 70));
return new ColumnModel(configs);
}
```

Comment: Could you please specify your question?

Comment: My GridFilters only works on the following conditions:
When there are only one filter added

Comment: Or all the added filters(More than one) are selected for filtering, Is it a OLD GWT/GXT version so it happens?

Comment: You could try to add filter configurations using [setFilterConfig](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/javadoc/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/grid/filters/StringFilter.html) method. You can provide a list with all the filter cofigurations.

Comment: Can you specify version of gxt?

Comment: I think you missed initializing the filters plugin. filters.initPlugin(grid);

Comment: I am using `extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.filters.GridFilters;` , 
 `extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.filters.StringFilter;` and the version is 2.3.0 for this plugin.
I also tried the method provided by Amit, `filters.initPluin(grid);` but it doesn't solve the problem.